# Where can I get Currency options historical data?

Tags: options, historical-data, currency

where can I get historical data for currency options?

For most part, google gives me links to binary options and other shady webpages.

Comment: Getting data from a futures exchange on Options on Currency Futures may be your best bet if you have trouble getting data on Options on Currency, which is a less transparent market.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks very much. @noob2

Answer (score 1):

You can find historical currency options quotes in [WRDS](https://www.library.hbs.edu/Find/Databases/WRDS)

. In WRDS, choose the option for Philadelphia Stock Exchange (PHLX) and then currency options. Make sure you have a WRDS account in order to access the data.